# How can I load Windows Recovery partition from Grub?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, dell, windows-10

I bought a Dell laptop that had Windows 10 installed and I created a partition to isntall Ubntu Desktop 16.04 LTS. At first, it al worked fine, but now, I have a lot of problems to load Windows, when I select Windows loader in the Grub menu, the computer freezes.

I tried the windows Recovery from inside Windows (I got in after many tries), and it all went well until Windows reloaded, after that, Windows got stucked on the Recovery scrren, and any option I tried it just restarts de PC and when I get into Windows, it starts from the same screen.

What I am trying to do is to restore Windows from the Recovery Partition, but I dont know how to acces it. In the Grub menu I have 5 options, ubuntu, advanced option for ubuntu, 2 memory tests and windows loader.

How can I acces the Recovery partition from Grub?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. That also means Windows fast start up must be off and NTFS cannot need chkdsk. Windows turns fast start up back on, so often you have to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu not grub or use your Windows repair flash drive to fix Windows.